# What is the best way to store integers mapped to strings so that the keys can be ranges in python?

Tags: python, types

What would be the best way to store (non-mutable) data that is of format:

```
doodahs = {
0-256: "FOO",
257: "BAR",
258: "FISH",
279: "MOOSE",
280-65534: "Darth Vader",
65535: "Death to all newbies" }
```

I have a relatively large amount of these type of data sets, so something that I can define the way of dictionaries (or close to it) and access via indexes.

Oh, and this is on Python 2.4, so please give really really good reason for upgrade if you want me to use a newer version (and I'll go for 3 :)

Comment: could you explain the structure of the data a bit more and how they will be used in your python code

Comment: Please upgrade to 2.6, not 3.  The really good reasons are all posted in the change logs in Python.org.  Do not waste your time struggling with 2.4 when then features you are asking for are trivially available in 2.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you don't have any "gaps" in your keys, why you just don't store the beginning of each segment and then lookup with bisect like suggested?

```
doodahs = (
    (0, "FOO"),
    (257, "BAR"),
    (258, "FISH"),
    (279, "MOOSE"),
    (280, "Darth Vader"),
    (65535, "Death to all newbies")
)
```

Answer (score 5):

I'd split the range into a tuple and then inside your class, keep the items in an ordered list. You can use the [bisect](http://docs.python.org/library/bisect.html) module to make inserts O(n) and lookup O(logn).

If you are converting a dict to your new class, you can build an unordered list and sort it at the end

```
doodahs = [
    (0, 256, "FOO"),
    (257, 257, "BAR"),
    (258, 258, "FISH"),
    (279, 279, "MOOSE"),
    (280, 65534, "Darth Vader"),
    (65535, 65535, "Death to all newbies")]
```

Your `__getitem__` might work something like this:

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    return self.doodahs[bisect.bisect(self.doodahs, (key,))]
```

`__setitem__` might be something like this:

```
def __setitem__(self,range,value):
    bisect.insort(self.doodahs, range+(value,))
```

Comment: How would inserts be O(logn), unless you go for a full blown BST? Isn't adding an element in the middle of a list O(n)?

Comment: @Kimvals, just a `)` missing from the end

Answer (score 2):

If your integers have an upper bound that's less than a few million, then you simply expand the ranges into individual values.

```
class RangedDict( dict ):
    def addRange( self, iterator, value ):
        for k in iterator:
            self[k]= value

d= RangedDict()
d.addRange( xrange(0,257), "FOO" )
d[257]= "BAR"
d[258]= "FISH"
d[279]= "MOOSE"
d.addRange( xrange(280,65535), "Darth Vader" )
d[65535]= "Death to all newbies"
```

All your lookups work, and are instant.

Answer (score 0):

```
class dict2(dict):
    def __init__(self,obj):
            dict.__init__(self,obj)
    def __getitem__(self,key):
            if self.has_key(key):
                    return super(dict2,self).__getitem__(key)
            else:
                    for k in self:
                            if '-' in k:
                                    [x,y] = str(k).split('-')
                                    if key in range(int(x),int(y)+1):
                                            return super(dict2,self).__getitem__(k)
                    return None


d = {"0-10":"HELLO"}
d2 = dict2(d)
print d,d2,d2["0-10"], d2[1]
```